# Include additional files in build using MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, msbuild-task, octopus-deploy

In the past we have used a combination of TeamCity and MsDeploy to deploy our projects. We've recently moved into using Octopus deploy, and TeamCity purely for the Build. This meant changing the build process in TeamCity and removing any references to MsDeploy.

In the past we've used confiiguration such as the below in our project file which included additional files and directories:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
<CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
  CustomCollectFiles;
  $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
</CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
```

```
  <Target Name="CustomCollectFiles" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
<ItemGroup>
  <UCommerceAssemblies Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..\Resources\UCommerce\ucommerce\*" />
  <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(UCommerceAssemblies.Identity)">
    <DestinationRelativePath>bin\uCommerce\%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
  </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
</ItemGroup>
```

However this now doesnt seem to get invoked whatsoever. It appears (to me anyhow) that these pipelines were created for use with Publishing from Visual Studio, or using MSDeploy, however we need to just include these files in the directory either before or after the build has taken place. There seems to be tons of references across the web about doing this, however they all refer to using MSDeploy.

Can anyone shed any light on how I can include additional files/directories in the build without using MSDeploy?

Thanks for your time in advance
dotdev

Comment: Do those FilesForPackagingFromProject  just need to be copied? Then something like `<Target Name="Foo" AfterTargets="Build"/> with a Copy task inside should do fine

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Octopus for deployment you only need to include additional files (reference assemblies, etc.) into code package sent to Octopus.

To do this one needs to use OctoPack for project packaging. Then add .nuspec file into the project, for example this line in .nuspec will add all files from some different location into the .nupkg package under "bin\additional" and will be deployed correctly by octopus.

Nuspec [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/nuspec#specifying-files-to-include-in-the-package)

Similar solution is discuses [here](http://help.octopusdeploy.com/discussions/questions/8937-including-additional-files-in-msbuildoctopack).